# call an activity from RecyclerView error

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I am trying to call an activity from `RecyclerView` with the help of **`onitem click listner`** attached to `onBindViewHolder`. 
when i try to start the activity it shows **`null pointer exception`** and an error occurs.

From `main activity` i am passing `dataset` and `context` and with the help of that context i am trying to start an activity

follwing is my code

```
public class mycard extends RecyclerView.Adapter<mycard.ViewHolder> {
static ArrayList<String> mDataset = new ArrayList<>();
static Integer[] image;
static Context c;

public mycard(ArrayList<String> main,Integer[] images,Context context) {
    mDataset = main;
    image=images;
    c=context;

}
public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder  {
    // each data item is just a string in this case
    public TextView mTextView;
    public ImageView img;

    public ViewHolder(View v) {
        super(v);

        mTextView = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.info_text);
        img=(ImageView)v.findViewById(R.id.cardimage);
    }


}


@Override
public mycard.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext())
            .inflate(R.layout.cardview, viewGroup, false);
    // set the view's size, margins, paddings and layout parameters

    ViewHolder vh = new ViewHolder(v);
    return vh;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder viewHolder,  final int i) {
    viewHolder.mTextView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            int positon = i;
            Intent intent = new Intent(c,ContactUs.class);
            c.startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
    viewHolder.mTextView.setText(mDataset.get(i));
    viewHolder.img.setImageResource(image[i]);
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return mDataset.size();
}
```

}

Follwing ERROR I AM GETTING

> 05-07 13:50:58.604    9767-9767/aptlegion.vivatoyata E/AndroidRuntime﹕
>   FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>       Process: aptlegion.vivatoyata, PID: 9767
>       java.lang.NullPointerException
>               at android.content.ComponentName.(ComponentName.java:77)
>               at android.content.Intent.(Intent.java:3826)
>               at aptlegion.vivatoyata.mycard$1.onClick(mycard.java:60)
>               at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4569)
>               at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18570)
>               at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:743)
>               at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
>               at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
>               at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5196)
>               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
>               at    com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
>               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:602)
>               at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

AND IN MAIN ACTIVTY

```
 RecyclerView mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView)        findViewById(R.id.my_recycler_view);
    mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
    mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
    mAdapter = new mycard(main ,imageId,context);
    mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
```

Please help me with the problem

Comment: what is mycard.java line number 60?

Comment: mycard.java is the RecyclerView  adapter

Comment: post line number 60 of mycard.java  file.

Comment: its "}" ending of onCreateViewHolder method